# Regional Climate in a Dyson Sphere

Tags: science-based, climate, dyson-spheres

A Dyson Sphere, being a sphere, is a uniform "equatorial" climate across the entire surface. I consider this to be a major problem.

Somewhere between the Dyson Sphere and the Dyson Hyperboloid is an ideal Dyson shape which allows us to maintain the variety of Earth's climates from equatorial, through temperate, to arctic in appropriate proportions.

**What shape should a Dyson Sphere be in order to have all the climatic regions of earth?**

Comment: @XandarTheZenon, the shape required to maintain an equivalent to our climatic variation. I know it's unstable, but we're not on hard science here.

Comment: I'm considering the possibility that if you created a Dyson Object who's centre of mass orbited the star in a correct ellipse it could be made stable but that's a problem for another day.

Comment: I edite your question so it is less likely to be closed as opinion based.

Answer (score 2):

How about a series of earth-sized 'bumps'. (Remember on a Dyson Sphere at 1 AU you can fit ***550 million Earths***!) Each bump would be closer to the central star, and the angle of sunshine on the rounded edges would reduce the amount of radiation/heat received creating a difference for airflow/ weather creation.

You could also go with artificial climate controls, such as radiating heat from the surface to the 'outside' in uneven locations to again create pressure/temperature differences to drive climates.  The correct placement of oceans and mountain ranges to vary the amount of moisture an area receives should finish off your climate variation.

Comment: I'd not considered bumps for this, there'd certainly be some interesting weather patterns around them. Though the variation in distance from the sun is negligible, it's primarily the angle of incidence that matters.

Comment: Variation: plates that swivel. This works well for a geodesic frame structure. Be careful not to let the weather control computer decide to kill everyone off by creating monsters, though.